# Toggling collapse in React thats being created by componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling an API and mapping the results to my state and I have a collapsable div being created too, but the toggle won't work. I am using react-bootstrap for the div and it is updating the state fine between true and false but it is not effecting the collapse.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/getall');
  await response.json().then(data => {
  let results = data.data.map(item => {
      return(
        <div>
          <Button onClick={this.toggleOpen.bind(this)}>+</Button>
          <Panel expanded={this.state.open}>
            <Panel.Collapse>
              <Panel.Body>
                {item.text}
              </Panel.Body>
            </Panel.Collapse>
          </Panel>
            <hr/>
        </div>
      )
    })
    this.setState({results: results});
  })
}

toggleOpen() {
  this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
  console.log(this.state.open)
}
```

So there are going to be multiple collapseable divs that are being returned and render onto the component but the `<Panel expanded={this.state.open}>` does not seem to be getting updated. It only works if I move the Panel on the render function

Edit: whole file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Row, Col, Button, Panel} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      open: false
    }
  }

async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/getall');
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({ results: data });
}

toggleOpen() {
  this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
}
  render() {
    const { results } = this.state;
    console.log(results)
    return (
      <div>
        {results.map(item => {
          return(
            <div>
              <Button onClick={this.toggleOpen.bind(this)}>+</Button>
              <Panel expanded={this.state.open}>
                <Panel.Collapse>
                  <Panel.Body>
                    <p>ffff</p>
                  </Panel.Body>
                </Panel.Collapse>
              </Panel>
              <hr/>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

console.log(results) runs 3 times on page load and shows:

```
[]
{data: Array(2)}
{data: Array(2)}
```

but if i do `{this.state.results.data.map(item => {` results shows as an empty array

Comment: whitch one? you're not using any identifier ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should not be saving components into state. As you've discovered, doing so can result in changes to state and props being overlooked and not rendered. Just save the data to state, and then create the components in your render method.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/getall');
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({ results: data });
}

render() {
  const { results } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      {results.map(item => {
        return(
          <div>
            <Button onClick={this.toggleOpen.bind(this)}>+</Button>
            <Panel expanded={this.state.open}>
              <Panel.Collapse>
                <Panel.Body>
                  {item.text}
                </Panel.Body>
              </Panel.Collapse>
            </Panel>
            <hr/>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>

}
```

Comment: Seems to be having a mapping issue when I try it this way, i'm getting `results.map is not a function` but doing `console.log(results)` shows that it has the data. My `this.state.results` is an array

Comment: if results.map is not a function, then this.state.results is evidently *not* an array. I saw you had an instance of `data.data` in your original example; do you need to do `results.data.map` instead of `results.map`?

Comment: When I `console.log(results)` it shows `{data: Array(2)}` but I tried doing mapping it by `{results.data.map(item => {` it gives `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` and then shows `results` as empty

Comment: `this.state = { results:{data:[]} }` in constructor

Comment: I'm assuming it has something to do with the inital render, because I only have that one console.log and it runs 3 times, the first time it shows an empty array

Comment: You're structuring your state in two different ways. In the constructor, you have state.results being an array. in componentDidMount, you're setting state.results to be an object with a data property, and state.results.data is an array. You just need to use the same structure in both places, so either update the constructor to have a data property, or update componentDidMount to pluck out the data.